# Threading problem in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I'm getting this Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code   Message="The
>   calling thread cannot access this
>   object because a different thread owns
>   it."

whenever I run the following code

```
public partial class MainScreen : Window
{
        Timer trm;

        public MainScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            trm = new Timer(1000);
            trm.AutoReset = true;
            trm.Start();
            trm.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(trm_Elapsed);
        }

        void trm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Content = System.DateTime.Now;
        }
}
```

guys any solution... I badly wann come out of it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DispatcherTimer instead:

```
public partial class MainScreen : Window{
DispatcherTimer tmr;    
public MainScreen() {
InitializeComponent();
tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
tmr.Start();    
}
void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lblTime.Content = System.DateTime.Now;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you modify Windows controls you must do so on the UI thread (the one that created the controls).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716472) for lots of details.

Answer (score 0):

To be short, you should use Dispatcher.Invoke method to update UI elements.