# WPF: How to load lots of large images fast into wrappanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wrappanel

I have about 45 decently large images (about 680x1000) that need to be loaded into a simple user control (rounded backborder with fill, image, textblock, and 2 side rectangles) and then displayed in a wrappanel. Virtualizing won't really help here since the images are to be all visible at program load.

I know inside of the BitmapImage init i can set the decodepixel width, which does help a little, however id like to load them all as full size since i want to be able resize the images with a slider without losing quality (this part works fast for the most part).  I know one possibility would be to set the decodewidth to be some number which i set as the max viewable size could help.

I tried the multithreaded approach found in [How do I load images in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716472/how-do-i-load-images-in-the-background) (first answer), however it caused the program to take a LOT longer to load!

Any ideas?

Current load code:

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
//bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 400;
bmp.UriSource = new Uri(file.FullName);
bmp.EndInit();
bmp.Freeze();
images.Add(bmp);
```

Sample XAML code:

```
        <Border x:Name="backBorder" Background="Black" Padding="2" Margin="3" CornerRadius="3,3,4,4" 
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
            MouseEnter="backBorder_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="backBorder_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonUp="backBorder_MouseLeftButtonUp" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="16" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="imageBox" Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding Path=ImageWidth, ElementName=me}" Height="{Binding Path=ImageHeight, ElementName=me}" />
        <Border x:Name="backRatingBorder" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="White" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border x:Name="frontRatingBorder" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="50"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="12" />
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

.

**UPDATE:**

Well i ended up making it more responsive by running the load image loop in a single background worker.  After each image is loaded, Dispacher.Invoke is called to create the wrap item.  After playing with it for a while i got it to show each item as it is created in the same time it took before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with the overall performance, just the loading of the images, you could try [this Multithreaded UI tutorial.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dwayneneed/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual) I managed to get it to work quite easily, but if you're loading all the images in a loop it won't update the visual until you've finished loading all of the images. The UI is responsive during this time, however, as all the loading is on a separate thread.

Alternativly, if you're loading all your images in a loop then you could try an [improved version of Windows Forms DoEvents method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe?view=net-5.0) (scroll down to the example). You'd call this after loading each image and it will give the UI a chance to update itself (process user interaction etc). This is the approach I used when loading map tiles for my project and is easier than the first.

Comment: I think my main problem is the actual loading of the images from disk into memory. I'm not sure if there is anything i can really fix here, is there? I load all of the images into a list, then i generate all of the wrap items with references to the BitmapImages from the list.  I can clear all of the wrap children and re create them pretty fast, but the loading itself takes multiple seconds.  I tried a Parallel.For loop to load the images to the list, but it caused them to load a lot slower, probably due to async disk access.